# How to prove $x_n$ converges as $n \to \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $x_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} - \log n$. Prove that $x_n$ converges as $n \to\infty$.

Comment: The (finite) limit $\gamma$ of the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is well-known: it is the Euler constant. Check here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant

Comment: Do you know Stieltjes integration?

Comment: @ÁngelValencia So if the limit is well known, why would this be false?

Comment: @ÁngelValencia Then why is it false?

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. I didn't read well.

Comment: Try using left and right Riemann sums to bound $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$ by something involving $\log (n)$ (since $\int_1^n \frac{1}{x}dx= \log(n)$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** A proof without using the integration concepts.

- Show that
  $$\frac{1}{n + 1} < \log\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right) < \frac{1}{n}. \tag{1}$$
  You might need the facts that the sequence $\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ increasingly converges to $e$ and the sequence $\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n + 1}$ decreasingly converges to $e$.
- Use $(1)$, show that
  $$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n + 1} < \log(n + 1) < 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n}. \tag{2}$$
- Use $(2)$, show that the sequence $\{x_n'\}$ is increasing and bounded above, where 
  $$x_n' = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n} - \log (n + 1).$$ 
  Hence $x_n'$ converges.
- Show that $x_n$ and $x_n'$ have the same limit.

Comment: Good outline. An alternative route is to show that  $x_n' = \int_{1}^{n+1}\left[\frac{1}{\lfloor x\rfloor} - \frac{1}{x}\right]{\rm d}x$ and bound the integrand above to conclude that $x_n'$ converges.

Comment: Well done ... +1.